# which one is a better storage for wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7

for data storage which is the better storage system.from the development 
 sql to Linq,
 isolated storage,
 application page etc.

isolatedstorage has certain drawbacks as it cannot persist dictionary etc.

please help

Comment: What type of data are you looking to store? This will influence your choice.

Comment: Your question is too broad. We can't answer a question like this.

Comment: @rakeshkumar - please do not mutilate the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your need:

- Isolated Storage is for persistence of non-relational data. Yes, it can persist dictionaries.
- SQL CE is for use when you need to persist truely relational data.
- PhoneApplicationService dictionary is to be used to come out of Tombstoning.

Try these two articles for better understanding:

1. http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/23/31-days-of-mango-day-23-execution-model/
2. http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2011/11/30/31-days-of-mango-day-30-local-database/

Hope it helps!
Thanks